"Spreading of misinformation" OR "spread of misinformation "
Why is first one wrong .
The spreading of misinformation on social media is becoming a serious issue.
OR
The spread of misinformation on social media is becoming a serious issue.

"The spreading of information" is not "wrong". It  presents the spread as something that is  being done.

As @TimR says, the spreading is the action being (intentionally) performed on the misinformation, whereas the spread would be happening if the misinformation were itself mobile—like the spread of flu every winter.

@PaulTanenbaum: I think that's a misleading comment, since it implies a different meaning when in practice the only difference is a matter of syntax / "parts of speech".

The first one isn't wrong, e.g. "The spreading of misinformation by politicians was a major problem at the start of the 21st century." If you feel that it's awkward, that's because it could almost always be rephrased to be more concise: "Politicians spreading misinformation was a major problem at the start of the 21st century." "Misinformation spread by politicians was a major problem at the start of the 21st century."

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spreading+of+misinformation%2C+spread+of+misinformation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

The first one is not wrong. It has a slightly different meaning, because "spreading of misinformation" is a verb phrase -- an action, as another comment said." The other is a noun phrase: "spread of misinformation", so it is a "thing" -- the extent, reach, or result, I would assume, of misinformation being distributed on social media. Of course, this is an important, complex topic, and it can be difficult to encapsulate the idea in a simple phrase.

I'm getting the feeling the first phrasing is not wrong. Can any on the commentators answering the question please post their comment as an answer?
